# Loading views with angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I saw in many websites like [twitter.com](http://twitter.com) when you navigate between views by clicking navigation bar menus, then views loaded only one time and the loading spinner appear only for the first time the view has been loaded. If you back to the view again,it loaded directly and the loading spinner does not appear again. 
I wonder, how can i do something like that using **AngularJS** ?. I need any tutorials to help me doing this or put me on the road.

Answer (score 1):

This is already a core part of angular. Have a read of the [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24templateCache) documentation. Here is a simple excerpt:

> The first time a template is used, it is loaded in the template cache for quick retrieval. You can load templates directly into the cache in a script tag, or by consuming the $templateCache service directly.

So when using something like `ng-include` to grab a remote template via a file, it will only be loaded once, and automatically placed into this cache and reused when necessary.

If instead you are wondering how you go about only reloading part of the page, then you need to look at `ng-view` (which is part of the basic route module), or `ui-router` for more complex hierarchical view layouts.

Comment: I'm using the routing feature of angularJS and `ng-view`, can i use `$templateCache` with `ng-view` ?

Comment: If you are using `ng-view` your app will already be using `$templateCache`. I am guessing your issue might have more to do with routing than caching. You might need to be more specific or post some code.